# Visual Studio SonarLint extension connected to SonarQube is generating warnings CA0507 and CA0064 and no sonar Sxxx warnings

Tags: sonarqube, visual-studio-2019, fxcop, sonarlint

I installed the SonarLint extension for Visual Studio and connected successfully to our SonarQube server and successfully ran Code Analysis to display sonar issues in VS. So it was working OK but for some reason I am now no longer getting any sonar Sxxx warnings and instead now see the following 2 warnings:

```
> Warning CA0507 Post-build Code Analysis (FxCopCmd.exe) has been
> deprecated in favor of FxCop analyzers, which run during build. Refer
> to https://aka.ms/fxcopanalyzers to migrate to FxCop analyzers.
> 
> Warning CA0064 : No analysis was performed because the
> specified rule set could not be loaded or did not contain any managed
> code analysis rules.
```

But I am not using FxCop and I am not aware of having done anything to turn it on.

If I check one rule inside "Managed Binary Analysis" the CA0064 warning will go away, but CA0507 remains and still no sonar Sxxx warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The "Run Code Analysis" menu items only apply to the legacy FxCop rules. You don't need to use those menu items for Roslyn-based analyzers (like the C# and VB.NET rules in SonarLint) - Visual Studio will automatically trigger the analysis in the background. See the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019#nuget-package-versus-vsix-extension) for more info.

If you are not seeing Sxxx issues being reported there are a couple of things to look at:

- Check whether you have the [Enable full solution analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-enable-and-disable-full-solution-analysis-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019) option checked. If not, VS will only report issues in open files.
- You've connected the solution to your SonarQube server so SonarLint will have generated a ruleset based on the Quality Profile. The ruleset will be in the solution-level `.sonarlint` folder. Check whether the rules you are expecting to report issues are enabled in the ruleset file. If not, update the Quality Profile on the server then close and re-open the solution. SonarLint will detect that the Quality Profile has changed and prompt you to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Compile again the project. With first compilation this errors will appear but with second compilation probably not.

No idea why, but it worked for me.